# How to present a pretty printed Java source located outside the HTML file?

Tags: java, javascript, html, pretty-print

I am looking at writing a tutorial for a Java concept where it would be really nice if I could write the tutorial as a HTML-document with pretty printed Java sources.

I understand I can do this with e.g. http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/ if I copy the various Java sources in my HTML document where I want them to be and put a styling class on the surrounding tag.

However, in order to ensure that the snippets are up to date I would *really* like to have the HTML page refer to the actual, real Java source files instead of a manually maintained copy.

To my understanding - which may be wrong - this is not supported directly by the Google Prettyprint library, but perhaps some trickery with Javascript pulling in the file and putting it in the DOM tree inside a `<pre>` tag could do it?  I would like the HTML file to be present in the local file system, so doing server side scripting is not an option.

My question is - how can I do this?

(I intend to have the HTML file physically placed at the root of the source tree.  This mean that all references from HTML to Java sources will be relative and without '..'.  I do not know if that is important or not.)

Comment: Hello Thorbjørn. Are you making any progress on this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access files directly using JavaScript. JavaScript is restricted in this way for obvious security reasons.

You will need your webserver to serve the Java files. You don't need to do server side scripting but the content of your Java files has to be available at some web address. If they are you can load the content of the Java files with AJAX and inset the content into your webpage.

Using jQuery loading the text could be done as follows

```
$.get('java/somefile.java', function(data) {
  $('#sourceCodeDestination').html(data);
  // Prettyprint neeeds to run again in order to see the newly added code
  prettyPrint();
}, "text");
```

This will load the url `java/somefile.java` get the content of it as plain text and insert it into the DOM element with the id `sourceCodeDestination`. For more information see the jQuery documentation on [get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/paldepind/VhWyx/). As you can see it loads a minified version of the Prettyprint sourcecode from a CDN and pretty prints it.

Comment: Would you happen to have working code for loading the content of the Java files with AJAX and insert the content in my web page?

Comment: I've updated my answer with code. I recommend you use jQuery since it makes the AJAX requests much simpler and it sounds like you don't have experience with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

if your users can accept the requirement of online access while reading your document, you could host your code somewhere like gist (https://gist.github.com/), and embed it in your html dopcument (see example by putting this into your document `<script src="https://gist.github.com/sangohan/6494440.js"></script>`)

Comment: I do not understand your comment.  I am fine with the _javascript_ needed for whatever magic is required being present on the Internet.  It is the _Java_ sources that is present in the file system next to the HTML file.

Comment: i meant put your java code on github instead of having it offline. There is no way for a static html file to read from the filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming [*prettify.js*](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/prettify.js) has been loaded previously you can invoke the *function* `prettyPrint` which takes arguments *callback* and *rootNode*.

```html
<div id="foo">
    <pre id="bar"></pre>
</div>
```

```js
var pre = document.getElementById('bar');
pre.textContent = 'function () {\n    return;\n}'; // assign code
pre.className = 'prettyprint';                     // assign class
prettyPrint(null, document.getElementById('foo')); // prettify
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/K3wvc/)

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, the source to prettify is placed inside a Javascript snippet and not located outside the HTML page.  Would you have a solution for where it is located in a file outside the HTML page?

Comment: As mentioned in another answer you would use Ajax to load the file into the element then run prettyPrint() on it. There's a basic tutorial for ajax at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/), or [thenewboston](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tp3Gw-oWs2k)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen this changes the problem from prettyprint to importing a file, which (if you're passing same origin) is easy with an _XMLHttpRequest_.

Comment: @PaulS.  How can I rephrase my question to make it clearer that I need to pull in an external file from the file system and pretty print it?

Comment: Then you're asking 2 questions; `1` How can I load a text file using _JavaScript_, `2` how can I prettyprint it? This answer answers `2`, for `1` use an _XMLHttpRequest_. If you're using the `file://` protocol, you'll encounter problems because of security protocols; so best to use `http:`, i.e. a server.